# Accessing element in async array

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have an angularjs2 app that receives a list of jsons from my firebase service. I want to access and display the first element of the list.

Here is what I have tried

```
<h1>{{(chapters | async)?[0].title}}</h1>
```

which gives me a Template parse error.

How do I access the first element of an async array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pipe like this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'first'
})
export class First {
  transform(val, args) {
    if (val === null) return val;
    return val[0];
  }
}
```

and in your html

```
<h1>{{ (chapters | async | first)?.title }}</h1>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ct35hvdf7RAEs4Ih492J?p=preview)**

Comment: Nice idea :) Shouldn't then this also work `{{ (chapters?.first() | async)?.title }}`. Never tried operators that need to be imported in bindings.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it like this:

`<h1>{{((chapters | async) || [])[0]?.title}}</h1>`

It's a more generic solution, works for any index, not only first.

Answer (score 1):

`?` (safe-navigation) only works with `.` (dereference operator) not with `[]` (index access operator)

What might work is

```
<h1>{{(chapters | async)?.length && (chapters | async)[0].title}}</h1>
```

but I'm not sure if `chapters` is subscribed to twice. In this case this wouldn't be a good solution. Angular2 does some deduplication in template bindings but not sure about `| async`.

Another approach would be to assign the result to a property

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.chapters.subscribe(val => this.captersResult = val);
}
```

```
<h1>{{(chaptersResult?.length && chaptersResult[0].title}}</h1>

}
```